# How many levels does an arbitrary Tcl dicionary have?

Tags: dictionary, nested, tcl

Let us say that I have a dictionary in tcl:

```
set dicty [dict create 1 2 4 "5 6"]
```

So, in the mind of the person creating the dictionary there is no nesting. Value of 4 is a string. Not according to the tcl engine...: See shell result

```
puts [ dict get [ dict get $dicty 4 ] 5 ]
> 6
```

Which means that the string got auto-converted to a dictionary. Needless to say, in languages such as Perl, Ruby, Python, this is easily tackled.
Any ideas?

Comment: If the string can be parsed as a dict, then you will be able to use that value as a dict. It's just what the answer to your previous question said. `5 6` is a string, but can be understood as a list and a dict as well due to how it looks like.

Comment: So no way to know a-priori...

Comment: The problem is, as kostix said, you don't need to *know* what types values are, you just treat values as being of certain type throughout the lives of those values, and the whole thing just works. Also, when you say that such is easily tackled in other languages, is it as easy to construct nested dictionaries? I think Tcl is besting them in that regard.

Comment: Almost everything in Tcl is fundamentally a string... it is just treated as a special type of string when you try to run a command on it. (And a command is just a string - well, a list - that you tell the interpreter to treat in a special way). This gives you great power - but with great power comes great responsibility...

Comment: The usual problem with such stuff is: JSON, pretty print...

Answer (score 1):

Both the keys and the value in Tcl's dictionaries are arbitrary values, and so may be dictionaries. It's not very useful to use dictionaries as keys, but nested dictionaries are fully supported (and may be nested *very* deep; I've made it to over a million deep, though this isn't recommended for comprehensibility reasons!):

```
set theDict {a b c {d e f {g h} i j} k l}
puts [dict get $theDict "c" "f" "g"]
# You can also use multiple keys with [dict set] and [dict exists]
```

Tcl does not distinguish at the formal type level between strings, lists and dictionaries. This is by design. All Tcl values are fully serializable by default, and will be automatically converted between types behind the scenes as necessary, according to what operations were used on them last.

Write what you mean to say and stop worrying about the types: they'll come right for you.